# Regex in Expect script passing only the first match

Tags: regex, linux, bash, centos, expect

Having this very simple script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f


set values "#host=CE101 #host=CE102"
set found [regexp {[A-Z]{1,2}\d{2,3}} $values CE CE1]
if {$found == 1} {
    puts "px is $CE"
    puts "vpx is $CE1"
} else {
   puts "\nfailed to match anything from\r\n$values"
}

puts $found
```

So my problem is that regexp is passing only the first found result to a variable and the second one is not being passed. I am sure that is the problem because of adding -all to regexp is returning `2` so I am sure that its matching both values, but I don't know why it's passing only the first matched, also I deleted `"#host=CE101` and it successfully matches CE102.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just missing a couple of options for [`regexp`](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/regexp.htm)

```
set values "#host=CE101 #host=CE102"
set re {[A-Z]{1,2}\d{2,3}}
set hosts [regexp -all -inline $re $values]
if {[llength $hosts] > 0} {
    foreach host $hosts {puts "found $host"}
} else {
    puts "no matches"
}
```

```
found CE101
found CE102
```